# maven unable to find artifact installed in local repository

Tags: java, maven

I've got multimodule structure.

```
breed-platform\
    application\
    json-dynamic-parser\
    console-input-lib\
```

Root `pom.xml` file looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lapots.breed.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>breed-platform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>application</module>
        <module>guice-annotation</module>
        <module>console-input-lib</module>
        <module>json-dynamic-parser</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`json-dynamic-parser` has a `pom` file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.lapots.breed.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>breed-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>json-dynamic-parser</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.lapots.breed.platform.json.sample.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I depend on that `module` in `application` module, with `pom.xml` that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.lapots.breed.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>breed-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>application</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapots.breed.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-dynamic-parser</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapots.breed.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>console-input-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.lapots.breed.platform.Example</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I ran `mvn install` for `json-dynamic-parser` and got artifact in local `.m2` repository

[image]

But when I run `mvn package` for `application` project I get this error

```
L:\groovy_project\misc\breed-platform\application>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.259 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-19T20:10:25+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project application: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.lapots.breed.platform:application:jar:0.0
.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.lapots.breed.platform:json-dynamic-parser:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descri
ptor for com.lapots.breed.platform:json-dynamic-parser:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.lapots.breed.platform:breed-platform:pom
:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

What is the problem?

Comment: can you put the poms etc. into a github project where we can take a look at?

Comment: You should always start building from the root location which means at the level where `breed-platform` is located and there a simple `mvn clean package` should work without any issue...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have the project on `github` https://github.com/lapots/breed-platform except after migration from `gradle` to `maven` it won't build `guice-annotation` module anymore for now

Comment: Take a look into my comments in [Issue 1](https://github.com/lapots/breed-platform/issues/1)